# Parallelisation in Armadillo

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, blas, armadillo

The [Armadillo C++ linear algebra library documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) states one of the reasons for developing the library in C++ to be ["ease of parallelisation via OpenMP present in modern C++ compilers"](http://arma.sourceforge.net/armadillo_nicta_2010.pdf), but the Armadillo code does not use OpenMP. How can I gain the benefits of parallelisation with Armadillo? Is this achieved by using one of the [high-speed LAPACK and BLAS replacements](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#dependencies)? My platform is Linux, Intel processor but I suspect there is a generic answer to this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay so it appears that parallelisation is indeed achieved by using the high-speed LAPACK and BLAS replacements. On Ubuntu 12.04 I installed OpenBLAS using the package manager and built the Armadillo library from the source. The examples in the `examples` folder built and run and I can control the number of cores using the `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.

I created a small project [openblas-benchmark](https://github.com/svaberg/openblas-benchmark) which measures the performance increase of Armadillo when computing a matrix product C=AxB for various size matrices but I could only test it on a 2-core machine so far.

The performance plot shows nearly 50% reduction in execution time for matrices larger than 512x512. Note that both axes are logarithmic; each grid line on the y axis represents a doubling in execution time.
[image: Performance plot]

Comment: My bad; I didn't see the logarithmic scale on the X axis.  2x is 2x, alright.  If I were you, I'd check it as the right answer again :=}

Comment: I did, thanks :-) Performance plots are often log-scaled since problems of polynomial complexity show as straight lines in the plots and the exponent may be read off the derivative of the curves.