# Efficiently randomly drawing from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, rcpp

Just wondering if anyone has ever encountered the problem where he/she needs to randomly draw from a very high dimensional multivariate normal distribution (say dimension = 10,000), as the `rmvnorm` function of the `mvtnorm` package is impractical for that.

I know this [article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/) has an `Rcpp` implementation for the `dmvnorm` function of the `mvtnorm` package, so I was wondering if something equivalent exists for `rmvnorm`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a quick comparison of `mvtnorm::rmvnorm` and an `Rcpp` implementation given [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simulate-multivariate-normal/) by Ahmadou Dicko. The times presented are for 100 draws from a multivariate normal distribution with dimension ranging from 500 to 2500. From the graph below you can probably infer the time required for dimension of 10000. Times include the overhead of generating the random `mu` vector and the `diag` matrix, but these are consistent across approaches and are trivial for the dimensions in question (e.g. 0.2 sec for `diag(10000)`).

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(inline)
library(mvtnorm)

code <- '
using namespace Rcpp;
int n = as<int>(n_);
arma::vec mu = as<arma::vec>(mu_);
arma::mat sigma = as<arma::mat>(sigma_);
int ncols = sigma.n_cols;
arma::mat Y = arma::randn(n, ncols);
return wrap(arma::repmat(mu, 1, n).t() + Y * arma::chol(sigma));
'

rmvnorm.rcpp <- 
  cxxfunction(signature(n_="integer", mu_="numeric", sigma_="matrix"), code,
              plugin="RcppArmadillo", verbose=TRUE)

rcpp.time <- sapply(seq(500, 5000, 500), function(x) {
  system.time(rmvnorm.rcpp(100, rnorm(x), diag(x)))[3]  
})

mvtnorm.time <- sapply(seq(500, 2500, 500), function(x) {
  system.time(rmvnorm(100, rnorm(x), diag(x)))[3]  
})


plot(seq(500, 5000, 500), rcpp.time, type='o', xlim=c(0, 5000),
     ylim=c(0, max(mvtnorm.time)), xlab='dimension', ylab='time (s)')

points(seq(500, 2500, 500), mvtnorm.time, type='o', col=2)

legend('topleft', legend=c('rcpp', 'mvtnorm'), lty=1, col=1:2, bty='n')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot jbaums. What would I need to add to this code in order for it to use openmp (multiple cores)?

Comment: I don't have experience with openmp, but the bottleneck here is the Cholesky decomposition, so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479258/cholesky-decomposition-with-openmp) might be helpful. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389117/parallelisation-in-armadillo/22584873#22584873) could also be useful.

Comment: [jbaums](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489704/jbaums) I initially got even better performance than you display above. However, as I increased the number of samples taken from 100 to 10000 the Rcpp slowed enormously (while the mvtnorm effectively did not change). I cannot figure out what is going on. Memory management? Do you have any ideas?