# Using OpenBLAS with GSL

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, blas, gsl, openblas

I compiled GSL and OpenBLAS from source with all default options in both cases. My GSL libraries are installed in /usr/local/lib and OpenBLAS in /opt/OpenBLAS/lib. How do I use OpenBLAS with GSL in C++?

The main reason I am doing this is because OpenBLAS utilizes all cores which Atlas does not in default configuration. My main aim is to multiply two large matrices (10000 x 10000) and perform 2D convolutions. Is there a better alternative to OpenBLAS or GSL for this?

I am using:

- Linux Mint 17.2
- GCC version 4.8.4
- 20 Core Intel CPU

I have been experimenting with the same thing in Octave with OpenBLAS. Will I get a significant performance improvement by using C++?

Answer (score 2):

I would use an existing linear algebra library like [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net). AFAIK it wraps your BLAS implementation for matrix multiplications. I like it because it provides you with a syntax very similar to the one in Matlab or Octave.

Other linear algebra libraries like Eigen will also do the job.

But i do not expect them to perform (much) better than Octave or Matlab as long as the call to the underlying library remains same. Also checkout [why matlab is so fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) and [how armadillo is parallelized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389117/parallelisation-in-armadillo).